# Cycles render stuck on Initializing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Whenever I try to make a render of my scene after changing something in my scene, whither it be adding a new object or moving an existing object around, the render gets stuck on the initialization stage. I then have to go to task manager and end blender because trying to cancel the render just makes blender unresponsive. Even worse, recently after reopening blender I now need to change the lighting and move my camera around a little bit or it crashes when I try to render. Strangely enough, if I do the things mentioned above I can then get a render to actually work, but then if I change anything else I will have to go through that process all over again. I cannot upload my project because I have bad internet and am using a phone to ask this question. I am using cycles.

Comment: Just wait for a few minutes, go take a shower or have a coffee, it's just loading stuff

Comment: Is it the Loading Render Kernel stage?

Comment: So yes, I tried waiting several minutes and the initialization phase does eventually finish in the couple of tests I have done. Is there a reason that the initialization takes this long sometimes and other times (like after a reboot) it goes faster?

Comment: That usually only happens on a new driver install

Comment: To be honest this is my first big project and I wasn’t very organized at the beginning and still need to get better at that, I probably just have allot of junk and need to clean up a bit. I’ll put the answer if that works. Also, I just realized that starting my last comment with “so yes” could have sounded a little rude and snarky but was not intended to be so, so sorry if it was seen that way.

Comment: I get the same issue from time to time.   It's very hard to say what causes it as it seems random.  It's why I always save my project before rendering it.  If your project is messy with overlapping geometry and unnecessary crap, take some time to clean it up and do some research into object size, attempting to reduce that.  It might help.